# find nth highest salary in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the nth highest salary in an employees table. I have got my result using one query, but I got one more query from Google and really want to understand the concept used in that query.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e1
WHERE N-1 = 
           (SELECT COUNT(e2.ORIG_SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE e2
                  WHERE e2.ORIG_SALARY > e1.ORIG_SALARY)
```

I really want to know how N is functioning here. I am really amazed to see this query and that it is working fine as well. I really want to know the trick in this query.

Can anyone please help me to understand this query?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So, what do you think the correlated sub-query does?

Comment: @jarlh, Inner query resultant work as input of outer query. In this case it can't work independently without outer query. But still how N is getting the exact salary without using order and other thing. Could you please en-light me? I'm curious to know !!

Comment: You should really be using `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.  Your query will not work (consistently) when you have duplicate salaries.

Comment: Kate, if I have the fifth highest salary, then that means 4 people (which is to say 5-1=4) have a salary higher than mine. So the query says select the record(s) in employee where 4 is = the count of employees having a higher salary than the record we are looking at. That would be me. Where this logic falls down is on how it doesn't address ties.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton, So inner query would fire first or outer query in this scenario ? Is this question make sense to ask at this point ? :)

Comment: Logically a Correlated Subquery is processed like this: For each row in the Outer Table run the subquery by replacing `e1.ORIG_SALARY` with the actual value of the outer row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e1
WHERE N-1 = 
           (SELECT COUNT(e2.ORIG_SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE e2
                  WHERE e2.ORIG_SALARY > e1.ORIG_SALARY)
```

`COUNT(e2.ORIG_SALARY)` outputs the amount of entries in this column in the returned data set. The data set is all the salaries higher then the one in the row your main query returns.

`WHERE N-1 =` means that it will get the result where that count matches N-1

So that means you will get the a row of the table employee where there are `N-1` higher salaries in the table, effectively giving you the row with the nth highest salary.

Keep in mind however, this is not perfect. For instance if you have multiple people with the same salary in the top 6, you don't get the nth highest salary, you get the nth highest sorted descending by salary.

Comment: the only thing I want to know..how the highest being defined with N ? May be its silly question.

Comment: @Kate It selects the salary where there a N-1 higher ones, so the N'th highest. Easy really.

Comment: you have no e1 alias table to reference

Comment: @Drew I am copying part of the code in the OP to explain. Its not the full one.

Comment: @Magisch I'm so glad that you helped at your best. But I'm sorry to say am still struggling to understand. :(

Comment: @Kate The inner select query returns the amount of rows in the table employee where the salary is higher then the one of the  row in the outer select query. The outer select query grabs the row where the inner select query returns N-1.

Comment: It is important to understand that even though you might be copying a fragment from a question, that the code provided here never established a reference to e1

Comment: @Drew I edited the answer to establish that reference.

Comment: @Magisch, But the result of inner query would be always same. Am I right ? If yes then how its comparing every time ?

Comment: @Kate No, it wouldn't. It resolves it so the outer query selects the row where the inner query returns N-1.

Comment: @Magisch, Do you mind if I ask you to update your given answer in more detail with example so that people dumb like me could understand ?

Comment: If you got multiple rows with the same salary this query will not return the nth row, it might return no row at all (you need to add a unique column to the WHERE). And to get the actual nth-highest you must switch to `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `DENSE_RANK` (hopefully this is the one you mentioned):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (
    SELECT e.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e1.ORIG_SALARY DESC) AS rnk
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
 )
WHERE rnk = n
```

There are always multiple ways to get he same result in SQL, some of them are not efficient and you better avoid those. Windowed Aggregate Functions have been added because of very inefficient processing for queries like ranking, cumulative or moving sums.

Comment: Didn't DV, but Op asked to understand the query they posted, not how to do it differently.

Comment: @Magisch: Well, DENSE_RANK is not only easier to understand, but probably much more efficient, too :-)